# In Angular.js do some operations after the download has finished

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have this factory that downloads some JSON data and adds it to the $scope.

```
myApp.factory('loadDataService', function ($rootScope, $http) {
var loadDataService = {};
loadDataService.data = {};

loadDataService.getData = function () {

    $http.get('/static/data.json')
        .success(function (data) {

            console.log("download finish");
            loadDataService.data = data;
        });
    return loadDataService.data;
};

return loadDataService;
});
```

I call the download service from my main controller like this:

```
$scope.data = loadDataService.getData();
// if I access the $scope.data here I get and exception because 
// the data is not yet downloaded.
```

Once the data is download and added to the scope I need to do a bunch of operations. What is the proper way of doing a bunch of operations in your controller after your data is downloaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give a callback function in `getData` like this:

*your Factory*

```
loadDataService.getData = function (callback) {

    $http.get('/static/data.json')
        .success(function (data) {

            console.log("download finish");
            loadDataService.data = data;
            callback();
        });
    return loadDataService.data;
};
```

*your Controller*

```
$scope.someOperations = function() { 
   // Your operations
};
$scope.data = loadDataService.getData($scope.someOperations);
```

You can also use `loaded` event with `$rootScope` like this:

```
$rootScope.$on('data:loaded', function(e, data) {
    deferred.resolve(data);
});
```